# Computing projective closure of $\mathcal Z(y-x^2) \subset \mathbb A^2$ in $\mathbb P^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Using notation from Hartshone's *Algebraic Geometry* (see below), the projective closure of $\mathcal Z(y-x^2) \subset \mathbb A^2$ in $\mathbb P^2$ is the closure (in $\mathbb P^2$) of
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal Z(xz-y^2) \cap U_x &= \{[a:b:c] \mid ac=b^2, a \ne 0\}\\
&=\{[a:b:c] \mid c=b^2/a, a \ne 0\}\\
&=\{[1:b/a:b^2/a^2] \mid a \ne 0\}.
\end{align*}$$
where $U_x$ the complement of the zero set of $x$ in $\mathbb P^2$.

How do we proceed in computing the projective closure?

---

---

---

Relevant information from Hartshone's *Algebraic Geometry*:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

To compute the defining ideal of the projective closure, you have to compute the homogenization of the defining ideal of the affine variety $I=(y-x^2)$. In general, to compute the homogenization of an ideal, you have to compute a Groebner basis of it, then homogenize all elements in the Groebner basis. Here, since $I$ is principle, its homogenization is just $I^h=(yz-x^2)$. Hence, the projective closure is $\mathcal{Z}(yz-x^2)$.